# Import-GPO from Backup and Link

Tags: powershell, group-policy

I have created 4 GPO's and used Backup-GPO in Powershell.

I have them in a folder called C:\GPOBackup in the default format (GUID).

I would like to find a way to import them back in and link them to the domain my current issue is when I try to import them back in I am able to do that, but getting them to link and become active against the domain is failing because the set-gplink will not use the Display Name of the GPO Object.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong CMDLET, If you use the New-GPlink cmdlet it works as I intended.